# How to build aosp for nexus..?

Tags: android-source, rom

Downloaded device drivers and extracted to vendor folder, but when trying to do lunch not showing on the list combo.

Comment: Nexus is not a single device, but rather a family of devices spread across time, each with its own build configuration.  You will have to be more specific: model and version (wifi or gsm or cdma etc).  Preferably you would use the device codename, which might in and of itself resolve your question.

Comment: yes, i'm working for shamu and hammerhead. I was downloaded drivers and extracted to vendor folder. But when call envsetup its not loading...
one more thing when i download kernel from developer site into device folder of source tree its showing in list of combo lunch,but "make" getting fail.

Comment: You are likely going to need to develop some problem solving instincts and familiarity with unix-style command line build tools to get anywhere with this project.  As is you have not stated an answerable question.